# Rails acts_as_votable contest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-votable

i'm working on a contest rails 7 app and i'm using act_as_votable to vote on user projects, but i'm stuck in the fact that user have to vote in every contest phases and vote have to be reinitialized for every phases but i'm my app it's the same vote count that is showned; how can i solve this please?

I tried to use a has_many_through relationship but it wasn't success.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can split the models into `Contest` has many `Phase` and then use `acts_as_voteable` for model `Phase` instead of `Contest`

The models should be:

```rb
class Contest < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :phases
end

class Phase < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :contest

  acts_as_voteable
end
```